# Error when matching records

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem :**

Code returns `0` matches.

**Code :**

```
Sub searchNames()
Dim loc As String

Call location(loc)

Dim loadWb As Workbook
Dim loadWs As Worksheet

' ~~ Load file location
Set loadWb = Workbooks.Open(loc)
Set loadWs = loadWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

' ~~ Init rows in loaded excel
Dim lrow As Long
With loadWs
    ' ~~ Set range for lookup value
    lrow = .Range("G" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

' ~~ Loop to remove trailing spaces
Dim TrimCounter As String
Dim NewString As String
For ind = 2 To lrow
    ' ~~ Set rows for trim
    TrimCounter = loadWs.Range("G" & ind).Value
    NewString = Trim(TrimCounter)
    ' ~ Write trimmed values
    loadWs.Range("G" & ind).Value = NewString
Next ind

' ~~ Set output worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL BRANDS")

Dim lrowWs As Long
With ws
    lrowWs = .Range("D" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With


Dim counter As Long
Dim rows As Long
Dim nameCounter As String
counter = 0
' ~~ Get controlPointNumber in ALL BRANDS
For ind = 2 To lrowWs
    ' ~~ Set controlPointNumber
    nameCounter = ws.Range("D" & ind).Value
    ' ~~ Start with row 2 in loaded Excel to omit header
    For ind2 = 2 To lrow
        ' ~~ Check if the name matches in ALL BRANDS
        If loadWs.Range("G" & ind2).Value = nameCounter Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next ind2
    ' ~~ Write the value in Worksheet 'ALL BRANDS' equal to the results
    ws.Range("L" & ind).Value = counter
    ' ~~ Init counter to 0 and check other controlPointNumber
    counter = 0
    rows = rows + 1
Next ind
' ~~ Close workbook ~ Byeee
loadWb.Close False
MsgBox "Scan finished! Scanned " & rows & " rows"
End Sub
```

**Screenshots :**

[image: ALL BRANDS] [image: Sheet1]

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Problem located. There are spaces in the values in `COLUMN G`

Comment: I am missing something. What is your code supposed to do? Can you elaborate with 2-3 sentences?

Comment: @Vityata I am supposed to check for the number of control point numbers in other workbook. So, `Column L` will return the number of values of that particular control point number that has been searched from `Column G` which is, from another workbook.

Comment: Would `COUNTIF` formula work for you?

Comment: Can you try doing a `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G:G,D2)` (you will need to modify `Sheet1` so that it refers to the correct workbook) in cell L2 and see whether that gives 0 too.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have 2 separate file though.

Comment: @Hibari You can refer to other workbooks in Excel formulas - it might look something like `=COUNTIF([Book1]Sheet1!G:G,D2)`, but `Book1` will be based on your specific file name.

Comment: @YowE3K but I am looking for a vba code for this :)

Comment: @Hibari - never ever declare a variable with name, that is used by the VBA or its libraries. Thus, variable names like `rows`, `columns`, `range` should not be allowed to be used. Unless you want to make your code unworkable.

Comment: VBA code for `COUNTIF`:  `lResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wrkSht_Source.Columns(7), wrkSht_Target.Cells(2, 4))` - where `wrkSht_Source` is a reference to the sheet with column G, and `wrkSht_Target` is reference to sheet with column D.

Comment: @Hibari But when you tried using the formula, did it return 0 or did it return the number you expected?  If it returned the number you expected, the error is in your code.  But if it returned 0, the error is in your data.  Once we know which it is, it will be easier for us to help you resolve the problem.  (I suspect it is the data, because the code works for me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the part of the code like this:

```
For ind = 2 To lrowWs
    Debug.Print lrowWs

    nameCounter = ws.Range("D" & ind).value
    Debug.Print nameCounter

    For ind2 = 2 To lrow
        If loadWs.Range("G" & ind2).value = nameCounter Then
            Debug.Print loadWs.Range("G" & ind2).value
            counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next ind2

    ws.Range("L" & ind).value = counter
    Stop
    counter = 0
    rows = rows + 1

Next ind
```

Then, when you reach the `stop`, you should have 3 different values in the immediate window. Take a good look at them, analyze them and repair the whole code correspondingly.

---

**Edit:**
Probably the error comes from the idea, that you can use something like this:

`Dim rows As Long`

Thus, VBA does not know what you mean, when you say `rows.Count`. Long story short, change the `Dim rows as Long` to `Dim lngRows as long`  and fix correspondingly everywhere.

Comment: what does the `Debug.Print` do?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+G`. It would display these values in the `Immediate Window`.

Comment: With a variable called `Rows` declared as `Long`, the expression `Rows.Count` would fail - but `loadWs.Rows.Count` and `ws.Rows.Count` would continue to work.  VBA can differentiate between a variable name and the name of an object's property / method due to the `.`.  It's certainly not a good idea to use such confusing names though.

Comment: I have located the problem! The one I'm searching from has spaces after the values. So I'll just trim them. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Hibari - welcome - but just another reason to use Excel formulas. They would do the `Trim` automatically.

Comment: @YowE3K - and I was wondering why I cannot replicate the `.` thing. Btw, it looks like a great job-defence idea.

Comment: @Vityata If you write `Dim rows As Long` `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.rows.Count` `Debug.Print rows.Count` then you will get a compile error on the `rows.Count` line but not on the `ActiveSheet.rows.Count` line (or, if you used `With ActiveSheet` `Debug.Print .rows.Count` `End With`, you wouldn't get an error on it either).  When VBA determines that it is referring to a property/method (i.e. there is a `.` prior to the name) it looks for that property/method.  Without a `.`, it assumes it's a variable - but some keywords will failover to being properties of default objects if no variable exists.

Comment: @Vityata And, FWIW, Excel would also give `0` with a `=COUNTIF([Book1]Sheet1!G:G,D2)` if `D2` was already trimmed but `[Book1]Sheet1!G:G` wasn't trimmed (or vice-versa) - Excel doesn't automatically trim values in that sort of formula.

Comment: @YowE3K - I was trying the trimming thing on `Vlookup`... :)

Comment: @Vityata a `VLookup` with an approximate match?  (It doesn't do an automatic trim with an exact match.)

Comment: @YowE3K - I tried automatic, its one less argument and I am lazy in writing. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150385/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-vityata).

Comment: @Vityata I added a loop that will trim the data for each rows. `' ~~ Loop to remove trailing spaces
    Dim TrimCounter As String
    Dim NewString As String
    For ind = 2 To lrow
        ' ~~ Set rows for trim
        TrimCounter = loadWs.Range("G" & ind).Value
        NewString = Trim(TrimCounter)
        ' ~ Write trimmed values
        loadWs.Range("G" & ind).Value = NewString
    Next ind`

Answer (score 1):

I always worked with the `.find` Method. For me it's easier and if you combined it with a dictionary you can do the whole range and can be sure that no Value will be missing. The code will take the range with values from column A and will count how often the value appears in the range. Hope the code can help you.

```
    Sub Makro1()
'Excel objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngLockin As Range
    Dim rngFind As Range

    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim idxRow As Integer
    idxRow = 2
    Dim strAddress As String

    'Initialize the Excel objects.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")


    Set dicSearch = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rngLockin = ws.Range("A2:A22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each rngcell In rngLockin



        'I Value is not in dic, insert it and start counting

        If Not dicSearch.Exists(rngcell.Value) Then
            dicSearch.Add rngcell.Value, ""

            'Search the four columns for any constants.


            'Retrieve all columns that contain X. If there is at least one, begin the DO/WHILE loop.
            idx = 0
            With rngLockin
                Set rngFind = .Find(What:=rngcell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
                    strAddress = rngFind.Address
                    idx = idx + 1
                    rngFind.Select
                    'Unhide the column, and then find the next X.
                    Do
                        rngFind.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                        Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
                        rngFind.Select
                        If Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> strAddress Then idx = idx + 1

                    Loop While Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> strAddress
                End If
            End With
            Cells(idxRow, 3) = rngcell.Value
            Cells(idxRow, 4).Value = idx
            idxRow = idxRow + 1

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Fell free to ask if you have a question.

Comment: This is an alternative method. Thanks!